# Is Kanban Board available for Visual Studio 2010 and TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, scrum, kanban, tfs-process-template

Some of my user had ask me about Kanban board for TFS 2010. I tried googling, i didn't find any answer.

1. Is kanban board available for tfs 2010?
2. can we integrate it with all the process template?
3. Is it a freeware? where can i download it from?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a free software that integrates with TFS 2010 and provides a Kanban board out of the box.  However, during my digging around last year I did find [Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com/) which does provide several agile tools for TFS 2010.

It seemed to be able to use most process templates when I looked into it, but I didn't push the tool hard enough to see how much customized process templates it could handle.

Comment: We have Urban turtle configured. It works fine. But my question is, Is there plug-in Kanban board like urban turtle. or it is a feature which comes with urban turtle. Sorry, if my question sounds silly. :)